# How to use the value of a array as select input

Tags: php, arrays, input, return-value

i didn't really know how to formulate my question, but i guess the title best describes it.

I have an array of dates (dd-mm-yyyy (2-9-2014, 7-10-2014 etc.)) and managed to show these in a select input. Now when i click a date and fill in my form, i get the key value returned of the array, so instead of showing "2-9-2014" it will show me 1, or when i click "7-10-2014" it shows me 2.

How can i show the date of this array when sending the form?

My array

```
array(16) { [0]=> string(8) "2-9-2014" [1]=> string(10) " 7-10-2014" [2]=> string(10) " 4-11-2014" [3]=> string(10) " 2-12-2014" [4]=> string(9) " 6-1-2015" [5]=> string(9) " 3-2-2015" [6]=> string(9) " 3-3-2015" [7]=> string(9) " 7-4-2015" [8]=> string(9) " 5-5-2015" [9]=> string(9) " 2-6-2015" [10]=> string(9) " 7-7-2015" [11]=> string(9) " 4-8-2015" [12]=> string(9) " 1-9-2015" [13]=> string(10) " 6-10-2015" [14]=> string(10) " 3-11-2015" [15]=> string(10) " 1-12-2015" }
```

My $dates var = the array.

In my view i call

```
<div class="form-group col-4">
{{ Form::label('date', 'Date:') }}<br/>
{{ $errors->first('date') }}
{{ Form::select('date', $dates, null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```

And in my form email i call

```
 <?php $datum[$_POST['date']]; ?>
```

or

```
{{ $date }}
```

But both will return the [] val of the array.

Comment: So change the select option values to the date

Comment: Please share the code you use to generate the html.

Comment: I am using Laravel @joeshmo, i don't know if you know it? But i can edit my question if needed.

Answer (score 2):

How about have your dates in a 3d array like:

```
$datesArr= array
  (
  array(0,"2-9-2014"),
  array(1,"7-10-2014"),
  array(2,"21-8-13"),
  array(3,"13-10-13")
  );
```

And then have your drop down like this:

```
<select>
  <?php for($i = 0; $i<count($datesArr); $i++){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $datesArr[$i][0]?>"><?php echo $datesArr[$i][1]?></option> 
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: It's that `value=...` part that OP needs to fix

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop, put the `<option>` tag in the body of the loop.